# Why do wave vectors separated by a reciprocal lattice vector represent the same wave?

Tags: condensed-matter

In my course, we modeled a system with harmonic oscillators.
We then found the dispersion relation ($K$ is the rigidity of the springs, $k$ the wavenumber):

$$ \omega = 2 \sqrt{\frac{K}{m}} \left \lvert \sin \left( \frac{ka}{2} \right) \right \rvert \, .$$

We understand that $\omega$ is periodic on $[-\pi/a,\pi/a]$.
I agree with all this.

Then it is written in the course that as $\omega(k)$ and $\omega(k + 2 \pi / a)$ has the same value, then the two wavevectors represent $k$ and $k+2\pi/a$ are same wave.
I don't understand this. For me the periodicity on $\omega$ just shows... a periodicity on $\omega$, not that $k$ and $k+ 2 \pi/a$ are wave vectors representing the same wave.

Why do $k$ and $k+2\pi/a$ represent the same wave?

***I don't want some extra arguments to explain this, I just want to understand the exact argument of the course.***

Comment: This issue confused me so much as a studetn, because the books are absolutely terrible. Take a look at the Wikipedia article on [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget that we are working with a crystal, which is a discrete set of point, and not with a continuum.

Look at the following picture, taken from C. Kittel's *Introduction to Solid State Physics*:

[image]

Two waves are represented, one with wave vector $k$ and another with wave vector $k'=k+2 \pi /a$; the wavelengths are respectively $\lambda = 2 \pi / k$ and

$$\lambda' = \frac{2 \pi}{k + 2 \pi /a} < \lambda$$

But you can see that the displacements of the atoms are exactly the same for the two waves: as far as the crystal is concerned, they *are* the same wave, and they carry the same energy.

As DanielSank correctly points out, this phenomenon is known in signal precessing as *aliasing*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In fact later in the course we showed that we can write the oscillation of a given point at xn of the lattice by a sum of exp(i*k*xn) using discrete Fourier transform, with k going from 2pi/(Na) to 2pi/a. Can I say that it also shows what your graph says (we can write the oscillations using only wavevectors inside [0;2pi/a]), we don't need larger wavevectors ?

Comment: @user3183950 Yes, exactly. Every oscillation in your crystal (1d, in the case we are discussing) can be written as a linear combination of complex exponentials involving only wave vectors contained in $[0, 2 \pi /a]$ (or $[-\pi/a,\pi/a]$ for that matter). You don't need wave vectors outside this interval because the crystal would not "feel" the difference.